# $T(X)$ has a closed linear complement in $Y$ then $T(X)$ is closed in $Y$

Tags: functional-analysis

I am trying to understand the proof of the following claim:

> Let $X$ and $Y$ be Banach spaces and the linear operator $T : X \rightarrow Y$ be continuous. If $T(X)$ has a closed linear complement in $Y$, then $T(X)$ is closed in $Y$. In particular, if $T(X)$ has finite codimension in $Y$, then $T(X)$ is closed in $Y$.

The proof is attached below. I don't understand they introduce the operator $S$. Can't they just start the proof from highlighted 3 lines?

[image]

Theorem 8 is:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They seem to be introducing $S$ (which is surjective and therefore has closed image) in order to apply Theorem 8 to obtain $M$.  We can't start at the highlighted portion because we can't be sure whether such an $M$ exists unless we know that $T(X)$ is closed, which is what we're trying to prove.